# Auto scroll while selecting checkbox from div using javascript

Tags: javascript

i have two division tag one for maintain overflow content and another contain the check box 
 when i click any check box i just need to scroll bar depending up on the check box 
 i.e there is 20 check box, 9-10 are visible, if you want other then you have to scroll scroll bar, but i want functionality like when i click on 9 check box and the user want to go forward then 10 check box come up automatic. this functionality already provided in hot mail for selecting the mail.

for that one i have use following

```
<div>
<div id="text" style="width: 500px; height:200px; border: solid 1px grey; overflow: scroll;">
    <input id="check1" type="checkbox" onclick="update(this.id)">Auto-scroll1<br>
    <input id="check2" type="checkbox" onclick="update(this.id)">Auto-scroll2<br>
    <input id="check3" type="checkbox" onclick="update(this.id)">Auto-scroll3<br>
    <input id="check4" type="checkbox" onclick="update(this.id)">Auto-scroll4<br>
    <input id="check5" type="checkbox" onclick="update(this.id)">Auto-scroll5<br>
    <input id="check6" type="checkbox" onclick="update(this.id)">Auto-scroll6<br>
    <input id="check7" type="checkbox" onclick="update(this.id)">Auto-scroll7<br>
    <input id="check8" type="checkbox" onclick="update(this.id)">Auto-scroll8<br>
    <input id="check9" type="checkbox" onclick="update(this.id)">Auto-scroll9<br>
    <input id="check10" type="checkbox" onclick="update(this.id)">Auto-scroll10<br>
    <input id="check11" type="checkbox" onclick="update(this.id)">Auto-scroll11<br>
    <input id="check12" type="checkbox" onclick="update(this.id)">Auto-scroll12<br>
    <input id="check13" type="checkbox" onclick="update(this.id)">Auto-scroll13<br>
    <input id="check14" type="checkbox" onclick="update(this.id)">Auto-scroll14<br>
    <input id="check15" type="checkbox" onclick="update(this.id)">Auto-scroll15<br>
    <input id="check16" type="checkbox" onclick="update(this.id)">Auto-scroll16<br>
    <input id="check17" type="checkbox" onclick="update(this.id)">Auto-scroll17<br>
    <input id="check18" type="checkbox" onclick="update(this.id)">Auto-scroll18<br>
    <input id="check19" type="checkbox" onclick="update(this.id)">Auto-scroll19<br>
    <input id="check20" type="checkbox" onclick="update(this.id)">Auto-scroll20<br>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function update(checkID) {
            var box = document.getElementById("checkID");
            var tag = document.getElementById("text");
            tag.scrollTop = tag.scrollTop - 17;
            setTimeout('update(checkID)', 1000);
        }
    </script>
</div>
</div>
```

how to scroll scroll bar when user select check box from the list 
 and also if user selecting forward than scroll down or user select backward than scroll up    as per the user requirement

please help me 
thanks in advance ...

Comment: Can you please, restate that question because it's a little difficult to figure out what you want

Comment: just see it ,i just put more explanations

Comment: I don't use hotmail and i do not know how it works. You say `... i want functionality like when i click on 9 check box and the user want to go forward ...`. How do you know that the user wants to go forward or backward?

Comment: that's we have to find depending up on next check box if the index of that check box is grater than current check then he wants go forward or other wise go backward.....

Comment: Initially there is no item checked so there is no current check. Additionally there is no current check with checkboxes because there can be more than one. It's not like radio buttons (or highlander). I've got what you want now. I will try to implement it.

Comment: please give me solution of this problem......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i did what you want. You will need jQuery for this.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="text" style="width:500px;height:200px;border:solid 1px grey;overflow:scroll;">
    <input type="checkbox" />Auto-scroll1<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" />Auto-scroll2<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" />Auto-scroll3<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" />Auto-scroll4<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" />Auto-scroll5<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" />Auto-scroll6<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" />Auto-scroll7<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" />Auto-scroll8<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" />Auto-scroll9<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" />Auto-scroll10<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" />Auto-scroll11<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" />Auto-scroll12<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" />Auto-scroll13<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" />Auto-scroll14<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" />Auto-scroll15<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" />Auto-scroll16<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" />Auto-scroll17<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" />Auto-scroll18<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" />Auto-scroll19<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" />Auto-scroll20<br/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var ct = $('#text'),
        cboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]', ct),
        lastChecked = null;

    cboxes.click(function() {
        if (!lastChecked)
            lastChecked = this;

        var _current = $(this),
            _last = $(lastChecked),
            cindex = cboxes.index(_current),
            lindex = cboxes.index(_last),
            t = null;

        //next
        if (cindex >= lindex) {
            t = $(cboxes[cindex + 1]);
            if (t) ct.animate({ scrollTop: ct.scrollTop() + t.height() * 1.5 }, 500);

        //prev
        } else if (cindex < lindex) {
            t = $(cboxes[cindex - 1]);
            if (t) ct.animate({ scrollTop: ct.scrollTop() - t.height() * 1.5 }, 500);
        }

        lastChecked = this;
    });
});
</script>
```

see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pbaris/Nv2tE/14/)

Comment: thank you so much bro pbaris this is really nice and work nice

Comment: can you please tell me what is diff. between this and $(this) in this program....

Comment: `this` is a reference to the `DOM` element. `$(this)` is a jQuery wrap element. You pass `this` in jQuery `$()` function to enhance the `DOM` element `this` with the jQuery goodies, like function `offset()`.